# Citrix Receiver can't show the direct draw softwares and failed to use notify user event

Tags: wpf, directx, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

Citrix Receiver can't show the direct draw softwares,only can execute it.My software is written by C#,use SQL server2005 and direct draw for skin.How to solve it?

The second question:I use the newest Citrix SDK and failed to use notify user event on the iPad.My Citrix is vertion 3.0 old and can't be updated because the company has buyed that vertion software.

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CMPRESULT rc;
    HANDLE hCMP = NULL;

    // initialize for STA (Single Thread Apartment) in COM
    rc = CMPInitialize(FALSE);

    ReportStatus("CMPInitialize", rc);

    // Open a handle to the mobile device
    rc = CMPOpen(&hCMP);

    ReportStatus("CMPOpen", rc);

    if(CMP_SUCCESS(rc))
```

I tested the code and failed.

Comment: I removed `directshow` tags, whatever this Q is about - it has nothing to do with DirectShow.

Comment: @Roman I am surely it is because of the skin.I use wpf.Even a small test exe uses wpf,the Citrix Receiver keeps blinking and shows all blue screen.

Comment: DirectShow is about video/audio streaming. Skins are an unrelated story.

Comment: I solve this problem by download a windows hotfix [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955692](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955692).It is because of WPF and DirectX.It took me a month to test every methods and today I solve it!!

Comment: By the way,you should not remove the **directshow** tags, someone else maybe help me solve this problem through that tag.

Comment: You should not *add* [tag:directshow] tag because there is no DirectShow even related, neither on your question, nor on MS solution to the problem.

Comment: I didn't know exactly the program is written by DirectShow or DirtectX .But they are related.I am sorry but this month it really take me too much time wasting and I am painful by this small problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version 3.0 iOS receiver is far too old to support the Citrix Mobile App SDK. If you must use an older version of the receiver then you won't be able to use this SDK.

FYI the official forum for the Citrix Mobile App SDK is here:

http://forums.citrix.com/forum.jspa?forumID=1366&start=0

You are much more likely to get a response to your questions if you post in that forum.